# Why does this code generate a DVI file that can't be opened?

Tags: beamer, viewers, dvi

I am generating a .DVI file with MiKTeX, that can't be opened.

By looking online, I found this reply:
https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=500

suggesting the problem could be related to PostScript. I actually found I couldn't open PS files either. Neverthess, I found that the problem was not the lack of packages, as suggested, for example, here:

https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13719

but the difficulty to find compatible versions of GSview of GhostScript. When I finally did, I was able to read the PS file, but the problem with DVI files remained.

Another suggestion I found online was to use an alternative viewer for DVI files, then I tried "Evince". Nevertheless, by trying to open the DVI files with such program, I got the message: "

*Unable to open document. DVI document has incorrect format*

Thus, I concluded the problem must be related to the source code, and I tried to build a minimum reproducible example, running without errors nor warnings, but generating a file that can't be opened.

Here it is:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Background} 

\begin{itemize}

\item W

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: with which viewer are you trying to open it? And why are you producing a dvi instead of a pdf?

Comment: what does the log say, did you make a dvi (or use xetex and make xdv for example)

Comment: you could fix your dvi issues, but do you need dvi? why not use pdflatex and make pdf (which is far more common these days)

Comment: if I try your example with xdvi the file does run but with lots of warnings about bad postscript specials, xdvi can only interpret a limited number of such specials, it would be better to convert the dvi to postscript then pdf and view the pdf

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I've tried first Yap, the default one, then with Evince. I'm used to produce the .Pdf at the end and work in .dvi

Comment: using dvi  for beamer is highly unusual and really will stress any dvi viewer as the document is full of dvips-specific specials to generate pdf effects. So the ability of a dvi viewer to show the document will depend on its ability to ignore specials it can not handle.

Comment: @David Carlisle: the output profile is LaTeX -> DVI

Comment: yap should work, but you must set the render mode to dvips (in the menu view or in the options tag "display"). (And you won't work "in dvi" then. Yap converts to postscript first. I don't see the benefit and haven't used a dvi viewer since many years.)

Comment: yes but nobody uses that for beamer, it really can only lead to pain, the dvi generated  has dvips specific specials for colour and so many other things, so it is dvi designed to be used with dvips, if it works with a viewer that is mostly by luck

Comment: why do you want to use a dvi viewer not pdflatex? especially for beamer which is making presentations with pdf specific effects

Comment: What I mean is that I can re-run the code without closing the output file, thing that I've never been able to do with PS or PDF.

Comment: That's a 'feature' of Acrobat as a PDF viewer: you can happily re-run in PDF mode with many other viewers

Comment: use a viewer like sumatra, or the internal viewer of some editor, e.g. winedt or texstudio both have one.

Comment: almost all pdf viewers other than acrobat allow the pdf to be generated while the viewer is open

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you: I've donwloaded Sumatra and made it my default file. It didn't change things: if I compile while the file is open, TeXnic Center stops and returns an error message.

Comment: then you did something wrong. Close everything and perhaps restart your computer and start anew.

Comment: I think I need to change somehow the "View project's output" and "Forward search" settings in the "Viewer" tab (where I've already changed the "Executable path").

Comment: @FedericoTedeschi Have you considered switching to an editor with build-in pdf viewer? For example in texstudio?

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz . I will try this as well in the future.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Actually, I've realized that the issue of getting an error message and the system stopping for a while only happens when I open the .PdF file after running LaTeX the first time, then I can keep it open safely.